# Element with responsive dimensions

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make a div with changing dimensions that respond to screen width, but also has minimum values. for example, the height + width would equal at least 1500px, but neither value would be less than 500px. I figure I'll need javascript for the variables, but I'm not sure how to build the functions. Any help?

Comment: you mean javascript, right?

Comment: With css `div { min-width: 500px; min-height: 500px}` if that is what you mean

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara  Yes, sorry

Comment: @Morpheus yes, but if one value is 500px, I would want the other to be at least 1000px

Comment: In that case it is a job for javascript

Comment: What exactly is the aspect ratio that you're after?

Comment: @Ihazkode I don't want a specific ratio. I want the height and the width to equal a specific number.

Answer (score 0):

go ahead and write this in your css

```
div{
 min-height:500px;
 min-width:500px;
 width:100%;//as u said that u want it be respond to screen dimensions.. i m presuming that u want it to be of screen's size
}
```

then in js

```
var myDiv = document.querySelector('div');
if(myDiv.offsetHeight+myDiv.offsetWidth<1500){
 myDiv.style.minHeight = 1500-myDIv.offsetWidth+"px";
}
```

Comment: he wanted the function... now he is smart enough to call the function at right time